# ListView en fragment

Tags: android-studio, listview, android-fragment, android-listview

Buenos días! 
Me encuentro desarrollando una app en Android Studio donde usare una listView en un Fragment, he logrado el uso normal de listView en activitys normal pero al momento de implementar este tipo de código en un fragment este no me lo permite,estoy realizando la utilidad de tres clases para esta finalidad las cuales son BlankFragment(fragmento donde pondré la listView),Lista_adaptador y Lista_entrada , mediante estas realizo el cargue de las opciones de la lista con una imagen , un texto mediano y uno pequeño , al momento de ejecutar la app , se detiene , se que debe ser porque en el fragment donde la ejecuto no esta implementado de manera correcta la inserción de los item a la lista solo que ese es el problema , no se que anda mal , no encuentro lo que debo corregir, agradezco toda la ayuda posible.

```
public class Lista_entrada {
    private int idImagen;
    private String textoEncima;
    private String textoDebajo;

    public Lista_entrada (int idImagen, String textoEncima, String textoDebajo) {
        this.idImagen = idImagen;
        this.textoEncima = textoEncima;
        this.textoDebajo = textoDebajo;
    }

    public String get_textoEncima() {
        return textoEncima;
    }

    public String get_textoDebajo() {
        return textoDebajo;
    }

    public int get_idImagen() {
        return idImagen;
    }
}

public abstract class Lista_adaptador extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<?> entradas;
    private int R_layout_IdView;
    private Context contexto;

    public Lista_adaptador(Context contexto, int R_layout_IdView, ArrayList<?> entradas) {
        super();
        this.contexto = contexto;
        this.entradas = entradas;
        this.R_layout_IdView = R_layout_IdView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicion, View view, ViewGroup pariente) {
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) contexto.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R_layout_IdView, null);
        }
        onEntrada (entradas.get(posicion), view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return entradas.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int posicion) {
        return entradas.get(posicion);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int posicion) {
        return posicion;
    }

    /** Devuelve cada una de las entradas con cada una de las vistas a la que debe de ser asociada
     * @param entrada La entrada que será la asociada a la view. La entrada es del tipo del paquete/handler
     * @param view View particular que contendrá los datos del paquete/handler
     */
    public abstract void onEntrada (Object entrada, View view);

}

public class BlankFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ListView lista;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        ArrayList<Lista_entrada> datos = new ArrayList<Lista_entrada>();

        datos.add(new Lista_entrada(R.drawable.bolsa_de_dinero, "BUHO", "Búho es el nombre común de aves de la familia Strigidae, del orden de las estrigiformes o aves rapaces nocturnas. Habitualmente designa especies que, a diferencia de las lechuzas, tienen plumas alzadas que parecen orejas."));

        lista = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

        lista.setAdapter(new Lista_adaptador(getContext(), R.layout.entrada, datos){
            @Override
            public void onEntrada(Object entrada, View view) {
                if (entrada != null) {
                    TextView texto_superior_entrada = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_superior);
                    if (texto_superior_entrada != null)
                        texto_superior_entrada.setText(((Lista_entrada) entrada).get_textoEncima());

                    TextView texto_inferior_entrada = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_inferior);
                    if (texto_inferior_entrada != null)
                        texto_inferior_entrada.setText(((Lista_entrada) entrada).get_textoDebajo());

                    ImageView imagen_entrada = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_imagen);
                    if (imagen_entrada != null)
                        imagen_entrada.setImageResource(((Lista_entrada) entrada).get_idImagen());
                }
            }
        });



        return v;
    }

}


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            BlankFragment fragment= new BlankFragment();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, "fragmentHome");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: " al momento de ejecutar la app , se detiene ", Fabian, no debes suponer te sugiero revises el LogCat y agregues que mensaje se despliega para tener un pronostico mas acertado del problema.

Comment: Si la aplicación se detiene te debería salir una excepción en la consola en modo de depuración. Se necesita la excepción y una referencia al código tuyo donde se causa.